# How do I make a tracking map using KML on an iOS device?

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, kml, tracking

I am trying to make a basic application which show my track on the map while walking. Is there any tutorial or source code.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: A friend helped me by this code sample code but it didn't run well http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31913717/MapTracking.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not at all an iOS developer, just never learned. However, I know that iOS has a [KMLViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) that might be useful. Otherwise you will likely have to parse the KML as XML and then figure out what to do with it.

Comment: Thank you. I have parsed the KML as XML but it didn't run well. Here is my code in this link (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31913717/MapTracking.zip)

Comment: Again, I'm not an iOS developer so I have no idea.